# How to use operator "?" with shared mpsc?

Tags: rust

I am struggling to apply the knowledge I received in the chapter [The `?` Operator Can Be Used in Functions That Return `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#the--operator-can-be-used-in-functions-that-return-result)  to my code with shared mpsc channel.

Here is minimal code:

```rust
use std::sync::{ mpsc, Arc, Mutex };
use std::error::Error;

fn main() 
{
}

fn sh_rx_get( sh_rx : Arc< Mutex< mpsc::Receiver< usize > > > ) -> Result< usize, Box<dyn Error> >
{
  let rx = sh_rx.lock()?;
  let r = rx.try_recv()?;
  Ok( r )
}
```

The error I got:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `sh_rx`
  --> src/main.rs:10:12
   |
10 |   let rx = sh_rx.lock()?;
   |            -----^^^^^^^^
   |            |
   |            returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |            `sh_rx` is borrowed here
```

Online [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d34786eda0b200dfdbeb0bca7fa608a9).

Any suggestion or hint?

Comment: user2722968's answer does a great job of explaining the problem and how to fix it, but there's another angle to look at it from: the `?` operator is for errors that can (and arguably need to be) _handled_ by the caller. It's not obvious how the caller could handle a poisoned mutex error, which is a consequence of a panic in a thread that held the mutex. Unless your program is actually designed to handle such cases, I would argue that `.lock().unwrap()` (or `.lock().expect("poisoned mutex")` is the _right_ thing to do here, and not a cop-out as `.unwrap()` usually is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this error is that `std::sync::Mutex::lock()` returns a `Result<MutexGuard<'_, T>, PoisonError<MutexGuard<'_, T>>>`. As you can see, the error case of that `Result` carries a lifetime that borrows the original lock (the lifetime `'_` in `MutexGuard`). The compiler is trying to tell you that returning an error via the `?` would return a borrowed value - `PoisonError<MutexGuard<'_, T>>>` - that was created, and is only valid, in this function; this would create a dangling reference and is therefor a compile error.

The offending local borrow ("data owned by the current function") is created implicitly when `sh_rx.lock()` is called. Rust will automatically reference the `Arc` `sh_rx` and then dereference from `Arc` to the `Mutex`, where `.lock()` is actually defined.

The reason `lock()` returns a value that borrows the lock even in the error case is that locking fails if another thread panicked while holding the lock; this could mean that the data protected by the lock is in an inconsistent state. `PoisonError` has an `into_inner()` method which acquires the lock regardless of this, and it requires the a borrow of the original lock to do so.

You can fix this by converting the `PoisonError` into some other type which does not borrow the lock. For example:

```
let rx = sh_rx.lock().map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;
```

This works because there is a [`From<String> for Box<dyn Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CString%3E-2)  in `std`, which is automatically used by the `?`-operator to convert the `String` into the `Box<dyn Error>` which your function returns.